# Can I make a custom filter inactive without deleting it?

Tags: support, filtering, custom-filter

I like Stack Overflow's filters for searching for questions, but I do not always want a certain filter active after I have clicked on it. Is there a way that I could make the filter not be active?

[image: Filter Tab]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s how to return to an unfiltered view after selecting a filter. Click on “Stack Overflow” (labeled *questions* on other sites) in the left menu:

[image]

You may also need to click on the sort (e.g. *newest*) you want to have.

---

Alternatively you can save the “unfiltered” view you want to see as a filter and then click on that.

Comment: I don't know where to click without [a freehand red circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/194720) ;)